# How to work with std::make_unique function and interface classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, abstract-class, unique-ptr

Suppose we want to implement strategy pattern. We have an interface `Base` and two derived classes -- `A` and `B`. Instances of `Doer` class can choose between `A`'s and `B`'s methods `do()`. And the question is how to complete the code to make how it should be.

```
class Base {
  virtual void do() const = 0;
};

class A: public Base {
  void do() const override {};
};

class B: public Base {
  void do() const override {};
}

class Doer {
  public:
    Doer(std::unique_ptr<Base> b_ptr) : ptr(b_ptr) {}
    void do() const { ptr->do(); }
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr;
}

int main() {
  Doer doer(std::unique_ptr<Base>());
  doer.do();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three major problems with your code.

1) `do` is a keyword of the language. You cannot use it as an identifier (like function name)

2) you take `b_ptr` by value, so you need to move from it:

```
Doer(std::unique_ptr<Base> b_ptr) : ptr(std::move(b_ptr)) {}
```

3) you pass an empty `unique_ptr` to `Doer`'s constructor, which is equivalent to passing a `nullptr`. You also try to instantiate the base class. It is impossible because `Base` is a pure virtual class. Use `make_unique` with a derived type:

```
Doer doer(std::make_unique<A>());
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Doer doer(std::make_unique<A>()); // or std::make_unique<B>()
```

The above is pretty much it. `std::unique_ptr` works very hard to implement the same coercion as the raw pointer it holds.